# Three-step method LCA in R (poLCA). Posterior probabilities from inclusive LCA?

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, probability, code-analysis

As recommended by [Bray, Lanzaa and Tanb (2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4299667/) I’d like to perform three-step method to classify individuals into classes by using posterior probabilities of inclusive LCA (LCA including covariates). However, the inclusive model is very different compare with the non-inclusive model if I include all variables of interest.

Conditional probabilities are completely different, as well as the number of cases per class. Therefore, the interpretation of profiles or patterns changes completely from the non-inclusive model (step-1) when using posterior probabilities of inclusive LCA (in order to assign the cases). 
My question is, am I doing something wrong? Is it normal to get these changes? Maybe procedure isn't correct. The model itself loses sense when looking at item conditional probabilities of each class.

These are the steps I took:

*To perform LCA to study profiles of sexual risk behaviors (using 6 variables) and analyze association with diferent types of drug use, gender and age (model 4 seemed the best choice).*

```
z <- cbind(sexrisk1, sexrisk2, sexrisk3, sexrisk4, sexrisk5, sexrisk6) 
lc4 <- poLCA(z, MyData, nclass = 4,nrep=10)
```

*Include all variables of interest as covariate for “appropriate” posterior analysis (as recommended Bray, Lanzaa and Tanb (2015))*

```
f <- cbind(sexrisk1, sexrisk2, sexrisk3, sexrisk4, sexrisk5, sexrisk6)~ drug1+drug2+drug3+gender+age
lc4.cov <- poLCA(f, MyData, nclass = 4,nrep=10)
```

*Once inclusive model is performed, I used the values of predicted classes and posterior probabilities (which I think poLCA does it via maximum-probability assignment. Not sure of this) to assign cases to membership classes.*

```
table(lc4.cov$predclass)
write.csv(cbind(MyData$code, lc4.cov$posterior), 'new.data.csv')
```

(NOTE: by incresing the number of nrep of both models (inclusive and non-inclusive) results of posterior probabilities showed less differences).

Comment: Maybe the solution could be to increase nrep of the inclusive model as it includes more parameters???